# Getting Installed Package Versions with Apex

Tags: apex, installedpackage

I'm trying to get installed package versions using Apex.  I know there is a [PackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_packagelicense.htm) class but it doesn't seem to include versions.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to install/use the [MDAPI Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi) or write your own metadata API call to [retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) the value. There's no native support for any of the objects that you'd use to query this information, including Tooling API's MetadataPackageVersion object and the InstalledPackageVersion hidden object (0A3 key prefix).

Comment: Thank you!  There were a handful of similar topics on SE but none that answered this specific Q.